# Hide Output if output is less than zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I finished a savings calculator but I realized that I want to display a different div with alternative options if the savings output is a negative number. I have tried a few different things and nothings has worked. I am newer to jQuery and I am having a bit of trouble. Any help is appreciated. Below is my code:

```
    function toCurrency(str) {
    let ret = parseFloat(str[0] === '$' ? str.substr(1) : str).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    if (!isNaN(ret))
    return str;
    return ret;
}

function calculate(){
 var savingsVal = (jQuery('#savingsVal').val());
 var totalSavings = 0;
 var regType = (jQuery('#reg-type').val());



 if (filterValues(savingsVal)) {
 totalSavings = savingsVal * 0.15 * 3 - regType * 3;
 }
 jQuery('#totalSavings').val('$' + toCurrency(totalSavings));
 }

if (totalSavings < 0) {
    jQuery("#negative-numbers").show();
}

else{
  jQuery("#negative-numbers").hide();
}




 function filterValues(eVal){
 return true;

 }

 jQuery('.results-area').hide();

 jQuery('#calculator').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 calculate();
 jQuery('.results-area').show("slow");
 });
```

Comment: what errors you will get in your console? Don't wrapp jquery with Parentheses as they are already wrapped by jquery wrapper. edit your code like this `jQuery('#reg-type').val();` instead `(jQuery('#reg-type').val());`

Comment: I don't actually get any errors. Thank you for the tip. I made that change to my code

Answer (score -1):

You have some logical errors in your code that are preventing it from working as expected. The number 1 mistake, is common, serious and preventable:

Forgetting to declare a variable.

In your code, `totalSavings` is used in two scopes but one of them neglects to declare it.

To prevent this error, and to provide enhanced performance and security, always start every script with `"use strict";` to enable ES5 strict mode.

Under strict mode, undeclared variables throw an error.

Furthermore, the toggling error itself was due to placing your if, `if (totalSavings < 0)` statement in global scope instead of within the calculate function or the event handler itself.

Coupled with failing to declare the `totalSavings` variable, making the condition initially false as well, `undefined` is neither greater than nor less than `0`.

I have corrected these errors in the code below.

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
  var totalSavings = 0;

  function toCurrency(value) {
    let result = parseFloat(
      value[0] === '$' ? value.substr(1) : value
    ).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

    return isNaN(result) ? value : result;

  }

  function calculate() {
    var savingsVal = jQuery('#savingsVal').val();
    var totalSavings = 0;
    var regType = jQuery('#reg-type').val();

    if (filterValues(savingsVal)) {
      totalSavings = savingsVal * 0.15 * 3 - regType * 3;
    }

    return totalSavings;
  }

  function filterValues(eVal) {
    return true;
  }


  jQuery('#calculator').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    totalSavings = calculate();
    jQuery('.results-area').show("slow");
    jQuery('#totalSavings').text('$' + toCurrency(totalSavings));

    if (totalSavings < 0) {
      jQuery('#negative-numbers')
        .show()
        .find('#negative-value')
        .text(totalSavings)
        .show();
      jQuery('.results-area').hide();
    } else {
      jQuery('#negative-numbers').hide();
    }
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Reg Type</label>
<input type="text" id="reg-type">
<br>
<label>Savings</label>
<input type="text" id="savingsVal">
<br>
<button id="calculator">Submit</button>

<div></div>
<div id="negative-numbers">Negative Numbers
  <div id="negative-value"></div>
</div>
<div class="results-area">Results

  <div id="totalSavings">Total </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this did not work for me and actually did not output any calculation at all on my end. Also the commas are not added to the output. But I do see a couple of the errors you are referencing. If needed I can post my HTML here as well so you can get a better idea of what I am doing.